# Upload InSpec Profile to private Chef Supermarket

Tags: chef-infra

All the online documentation points to uploading Cookbooks only.

Inspec Profiles exist in the public one, as seen [here](https://supermarket.chef.io/tools/linux-baseline).

How do I upload an InSpec Profile to a private Chef Supermarket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiles are not uploaded to the supermarket, the supermarket has references to the repo.

Go to https://supermarket.chef.io/tools-directory and add a new tool `compliance_profile`.

You can see all registered profiles in https://supermarket.chef.io/tools?type=compliance_profile